# Cannot convert []string to []interface {}

Tags: type-conversion, go

I'm writing some code, and I need it to catch the arguments and pass them through `fmt.Println`
(I want its default behaviour, to write arguments separated by spaces and followed by a newline). However it takes `[]interface {}` but `flag.Args()` returns a `[]string`.
Here's the code example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "flag"
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Println(flag.Args()...)
}
```

This returns the following error:

```
./example.go:10: cannot use args (type []string) as type []interface {} in function argument
```

Is this a bug? Shouldn't `fmt.Println` take **any** array? By the way, I've also tried to do this:

```
var args = []interface{}(flag.Args())
```

but I get the following error:

```
cannot convert flag.Args() (type []string) to type []interface {}
```

Is there a "Go" way to workaround this?

Comment: I was messing with a simple example (`go run test.go some test flags`), and it seemed to work when changing `flags.Args()...` to just `flag.Args()` (output is `[some test flags]`, followed by the newline; also seemed to work with registering actual flags). Won't pretend to understand why, and Stephen's answer is way more informative anyway :)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

This is not a bug. `fmt.Println()` requires a `[]interface{}` type. That means, it must be a slice of `interface{}` values and not "any slice". In order to convert the slice, you will need to loop over and copy each element.

```
old := flag.Args()
new := make([]interface{}, len(old))
for i, v := range old {
    new[i] = v
}
fmt.Println(new...)
```

The reason you can't use any slice is that conversion between a `[]string` and a `[]interface{}` requires the memory layout to be changed and happens in O(n) time. Converting a type to an `interface{}` requires O(1) time. If they made this for loop unnecessary, the compiler would still need to insert it.

Comment: If each iteration requires O(1) time, wouldn't the whole loop need O(n) time?

Comment: If every element in the slice satisfies `interface{}`, then a function receiving `[]string` instead should have no problem, since every element inside satisfies the interface, is it?

Comment: By the way, I found this link in golang-nuts: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/Il-tO1xtAyE/discussion

Comment: Yes, each iteration requires O(1) time and the loop requires O(n) time. That is what I said. As for the function receiving a `[]string`, it expects a `interface{}`. An `interface{}` has a different memory layout from a `string` so the fact that each element needs to be converted is the problem.

Comment: @karlrh: No, suppose the `Println` function modifies the slice, and sets some elements (it doesn't, but suppose it does). Then it can put any `interface{}` into the slice, which should only have `string`s. What you really want is something like the Java Generics wildcard `Slice<? extends []interface{}>`, but that doesn't exist in Go.

Comment: Append is magical. It is built-in and treated specially by the language. Other examples include `new()`, `len()`, and `copy()`. http://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices

Comment: Explicit conversion to `interface{}` is unnecessary, instead of `new[i] = interface{}(v)` you can simply write `new[i] = v`.

Comment: Today I learned 'new' is a not a reserve keyword! Nor is make!

Answer (score 14):

In this case, a type conversion is unnecessary. Simply pass the `flag.Args()` value to `fmt.Println`.

---

> Question:
>
> Cannot convert []string to []interface {}
>
> I'm writing some code, and I need it to catch the arguments and pass
>   them through fmt.Println (I want its default behaviour, to write
>   arguments separated by spaces and followed by a newline).
>
> Here's the code example:
>
> ```
> package main
>
> import (
>     "fmt"
>     "flag"
> )
>
> func main() {
>     flag.Parse()
>     fmt.Println(flag.Args()...)
> }
> ```

---

> [Package flag](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/)
>
> `import "flag"`
>
> [func Args](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Args)
>
> `func Args() []string`
>
> `Args` returns the non-flag command-line arguments.

---

> [Package fmt](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)
>
> `import "fmt"`
>
> [func Println](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println)
>
> `func Println(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)`
>
> `Println` formats using the default formats for its operands and
>   writes to standard output. Spaces are always added between operands
>   and a newline is appended. It returns the number of bytes written and
>   any write error encountered.

---

In this case, a type conversion is unnecessary. Simply pass the `flag.Args()` value to `fmt.Println`, which uses reflection to interpret the value as type `[]string`. Package [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) implements run-time reflection, allowing a program to manipulate objects with arbitrary types. For example,

`args.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Println(flag.Args())
}
```

Output:

```
$ go build args.go
$ ./args arg0 arg1
[arg0 arg1]
$
```

Comment: If I wanted to omit the brackets, would the conversion still be unnecessary?

Answer (score 11):

If it's only a slice of strings you want to print, you can avoid conversion and get the exact same output by joining:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "flag"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    s := strings.Join(flag.Args(), " ")
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Go, a function can only accept arguments of the types specified in the parameter list in the function definition.  The variadic parameter language feature complicates that a bit, but it follows well-defined rules.

The function signature for `fmt.Println` is:

```
func Println(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
```

Per the [language specifiction](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types),

> The final incoming parameter in a function signature may have a type prefixed with .... A function with such a parameter is called variadic and may be invoked with zero or more arguments for that parameter.

This means you can pass `Println` a list of arguments of `interface{}` type.  Since all types implement the empty interface, you can pass a list of arguments of any type, which is how you're able to call `Println(1, "one", true)`, for example, without error.  See the ["Passing arguments to ... parameters" section](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters) of the language specification:

> the value passed is a new slice of type []T with a new underlying array whose successive elements are the actual arguments, which all must be assignable to T.

The part that's giving you trouble is right after that in the specification:

> If the final argument is assignable to a slice type []T, it may be passed unchanged as the value for a ...T parameter if the argument is followed by .... In this case no new slice is created.

`flag.Args()` is type `[]string`.  Since `T` in `Println` is `interface{}`, `[]T` is `[]interface{}`.  So the question comes down to whether a string slice value is assignable to a variable of interface slice type.  You can easily test that in your go code by attempting an assignment, for example:

```
s := []string{}
var i []interface{}
i = s
```

If you attempt such an assignment, the compiler will output this error message:

```
cannot use s (type []string) as type []interface {} in assignment
```

And that's why you can't use the ellipsis after a string slice as an argument to `fmt.Println`.  It's not a bug, it's working as intended.

There are still lots of ways you can print `flag.Args()` with `Println`, such as

```
fmt.Println(flag.Args())
```

(which will output as `[elem0 elem1 ...]`, per [fmt package documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt))

or

```
fmt.Println(strings.Join(flag.Args(), ` `)
```

(which will output the string slice elements, each separated by a single space) using [the Join function in the strings package](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Join) with a string separator, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible using reflection, but I don't know if it's a good solution

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
)

type User struct {
    Name string
    Age  byte
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Println(String(flag.Args()))
    fmt.Println(String([]string{"hello", "world"}))
    fmt.Println(String([]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}))
    u1, u2 := User{Name: "John", Age: 30},
        User{Name: "Not John", Age: 20}
    fmt.Println(String([]User{u1, u2}))
}

func String(v interface{}) string {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    if val.Kind() == reflect.Array || val.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        l := val.Len()
        if l == 0 {
            return ""
        }
        if l == 1 {
            return fmt.Sprint(val.Index(0))
        }
        sb := strings.Builder{}
        sb.Grow(l * 4)
        sb.WriteString(fmt.Sprint(val.Index(0)))
        for i := 1; i < l; i++ {
            sb.WriteString(",")
            sb.WriteString(fmt.Sprint(val.Index(i)))
        }
        return sb.String()
    }

    return fmt.Sprintln(v)
}
```

**Output:**

```
$ go run .\main.go arg1 arg2
arg1,arg2
hello,world
1,2,3,4,5,6
{John 30},{Not John 20}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to just iterate the slice:

```
package main
import "flag"

func main() {
   flag.Parse()
   for _, each := range flag.Args() {
      println(each)
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`fmt.Println` takes *variadic parameter*

> func Println(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)

Its possible to print `flag.Args()` without converting into `[]interface{}`

```
func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Println(flag.Args())
}
```

Comment: `fmt.Println`'s signature hasn't changed in over 6 years (and that was just a package change for `error`). Even if it had, the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters) clearly says ` variadic with a final parameter p of type ...T, then within f the type of p is equivalent to type []T.` so it wouldn't matter. `fmt.Println(flags.Args()...)` still does not work (you're missing the slice expansion), `fmt.Println(flags.Args())` always worked.

Comment: How did you get this info that fmt.Println's signature hasn't changed in over 6 years? Did you checked source code?

Comment: Yup: https://github.com/golang/go/blame/release-branch.go1.10/src/fmt/print.go#L260 (on the 1.10 branch)

Comment: The comment on the op suggest that using `flag.Args()` solely as argument to `fmt.Println` worked back that time. (It would be surprising if it did not at that time)

Comment: So? If there exist a comment, that means my answer should be down voted?

Comment: @leafbebop where did you get this rules?

Comment: I vote the answer down because it is not helpful. It does not answer the question. My comment served to tell you that there is nothing new. And I think to downvote is a very personal right of a user that does not need to be justified.

Comment: And I think your edit to the question makes the question less general and more confusing. Is there really anything that requires revision?