# Unmarshal JSON object of strings, ints and arrays into a map

Tags: arrays, json, dictionary, go

I like to unmarshal a JSON string using Decode():

```
var message Message
decoder := json.NewDecoder(s)
err = decoder.Decode(&message)
```

My data structure is

```
type Message map[string]interface{}
```

The test data is as follows:

```
{
  "names": [
    "HINDERNIS",
    "TROCKNET",
    "UMGEBENDEN"
  ], 
  "id":1189,
  "command":"checkNames"
}
```

It's working fine for numbers and strings, but with the string array I get following panic:

```
panic: interface conversion: interface is []interface {}, not []string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not possible by conversion because a [slice of struct != slice of interface it implements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994679/golang-slice-of-struct-slice-of-interface-it-implements)!
either you can get the elements one by one and put them into a `[]string` like this: http://play.golang.org/p/1yqScF9yVX

or better, use the capabilities of the json package to unpack the data in your model format : http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_Unmarshal

Comment: I chose the second. I changed the map[string]interface{} type into a struct {Id int Command string Names []string } and then used Decode() as I did before. Works fine.