# Why golang struct array cannot be assigned to an interface array

Tags: go

I'm trying to achieve something as below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    Value int
}

func main() {
    x := []MyStruct{
        MyStruct{
            Value : 5,
        },
        MyStruct{
            Value : 6,
        },
    }
    var y []interface{}
    y = x // This throws a compile time error

    _,_ = x,y
}
```

This gives a compile time error:

```
sample.go:21: cannot use x (type []MyStruct) as type []interface {} in assignment
```

Why is this not possible?.If not is there any other way to hold generic object arrays in  Golang?

Comment: Because array of *a generic type* is not equal to array of  *a struct*. Just use `var y interface{}` instead of array. Type `interface{}` can be used to store **any type of variable** in Golang.

Comment: @putu thanks changing to interface{} solved the problem

Comment: See https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Comment: Possible duplicate of [golang: slice of struct != slice of interface it implements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994679/golang-slice-of-struct-slice-of-interface-it-implements)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`interface{}` is stored as a two word pair, one word describing the underlying type information and one word describing the data within that interface:

[image]

https://research.swtch.com/interfaces

Here we see the first word stores the type information and the second the data within `b`.

Struct types are stored differently, they do not have this pairing. Their fields of a struct are laid out next to one another in memory.

[image]

https://research.swtch.com/godata

You cannot convert one to the other because they do not have the same representation in memory.

> It is necessary to copy the elements individually to the destination
>   slice.

https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

To answer your last question, you could have `[]interface` which is a slice of interfaces, where each interface is represented as above, or just `interface{}` where the underlying type held in that interface is `[]MyStruct`

```
var y interface{}
y = x
```

or

```
y := make([]interface{}, len(x))
for i, v := range x {
    y[i] = v
}
```

Comment: Will this duplicate everything in RAM? I don't see pointers used so I guess everything is copied by value.

Comment: If you use the second option: "or just interface{} where the underlying type held in that interface is []MyStruct" then slices are already reference types, so there would be no copying of the underlying data. If you copy your data out of the []MySlice and into []interface{}, then yes, you will have a copy of the data.