# How do you pass a slice of *interface{} as arguments?

Tags: go

I want to use [`Scan()`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Scan) in package `sql`, but the number of columns, and hence the number of arguments, will change at runtime. This is the signature of `Scan()`:

```
func (rs *Rows) Scan(dest ...interface{}) error
```

According to the documentation, `*interface{}` is one of the types accepted by `Scan()`. So I want to create a slice of `[]*interface{}` and that expand as arguments.

This is what I thought would work:

```
func query(database *sql.DB) {
    rows, _ := database.Query("select * from testTable")

    for rows.Next() {
        data := make([]*interface{}, 2)
        err := rows.Scan(data...) // Compilation error
        fmt.Printf("%v%v\n", *data[0], *data[1])
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
    }
}
```

Compilation fails with `cannot use data (type []*interface {}) as type []interface {} in argument to rows.Scan`. I thought that `data...` would expand to `&data[0], &data[1]`, but apparently not. I don't understand the error message. `*interface{}` is compatible with `interface{}`, so why can't I expand the slice of pointers to interface types?

This works:

```
func query(database *sql.DB) {
    rows, _ := database.Query("select * from testTable")

    for rows.Next() {
        data := make([]*interface{}, 2)
        err := rows.Scan(&data[0], &data[1]) // Only changed this line
        fmt.Printf("%v%v\n", *data[0], *data[1]) // Outputs "[48][116 101 120 116]"
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
    }
}
```

I can't use this however, because the number of columns is unknown at compile time. How can I write this code so that I can pass a variable number of `*interface{}` to `rows.Scan()`?

Comment: Why do you want `[]*interface{}` instead of `[]interface{}`?

Comment: I just thought that `[]*interface{}` gets me closest to the answer. I will edit my question to add this detail.

Comment: Pointers to interfaces are almost never the right approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you must not use `[]*interface{}` slice of pointers to interface rather than `[]interface{}` where the interfaces are pointers. `[]*interface{}` is different from `[]interface{}`. Just create a slice of interfaces where each element is a pointer to a concrete type.

Here is a snippet how you would do this.

```
var x int
var s string

data := []interface{}{&x, &s}

rows.Scan(data...)
```

Note on the use of the `...` spread operator.

Here are some related questions that will explain a bit more:

[golang: slice of struct != slice of interface it implements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994679/golang-slice-of-struct-slice-of-interface-it-implements)

[Cannot convert []string to []interface {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990338/cannot-convert-string-to-interface/)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to pass a `[]*interface{}` (perhaps you don't know the concrete types of the output) you must first wrap each `*interface{}` in a `interface{}`:

```
values := make([]interface{}, columnsCount)
for i := range values {
    values[i] = new(interface{})
}
```

Individual values passed into a `...interface{}` parameter are automatically wrapped in a `interface{}`, but just like `[]int...` won't satisfy `...interface{}`, neither will `[]*interface{}...`.

Comment: This works great if you don't know anything about the query. Thanks!