# Convert slice of struct to slice of interface

Tags: go, neo4j

How do I convert the following slice of struct to slice of interface?

```
type BatchImportData struct {
    Name string
    SetHash []string
    SetMembers []string
}

var b []BatchImportData
```

This is so I can batch import data into Neo4j, as the Neo4j driver requires a slice of interface when the slice of struct is passed as a parameter.

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver

Cypher Type Driver Type

List    []interface{}

Comment: You need to loop over the slice and convert each and append it to a `[]interface`

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over the struct slice and append it to the interface slice.

```
    var b []BatchImportData = []BatchImportData{}

    var c []interface{}

    for _, b := range b {
        c = append(c, b)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your doubt may be something along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12990338/8565339), in which case you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12994852/8565339) quite helpful.

So you will need to loop over the slice and copy each element. Something like:

```
var b []BatchImportData
interfaceSlice := make([]interface{}, len(b))
for i, v := range b {
  interfaceSlice[i] = v
}
```