# GO Generic type of array in function parameter

Tags: go

I have this function:

```
func functionX(collection []*interface{}) {
    ...
    response, err := json.MarshalIndent(collection, "", "  ")
    ...
}
```

I want the **collection** parameter to allow arrays of any kind, that's why I tried with ***interface{}** but I'm receiving errors like this:

```
cannot use MyDataType (type []*model.MyDataType) as type []*interface {} in argument to middleware.functionX
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot convert \[\]string to \[\]interface {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990338/cannot-convert-string-to-interface)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it that way, however you can easily do this:

```
func functionX(collection interface{}) error {
    ...
    response, err := json.MarshalIndent(collection, "", "  ")
    ...
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/EcUG3AYVqY)

Comment: Thanks, I already figured it out, but is exactly as you say :) It's working like a charm