# How to get slice underlying value via reflect.Value

Tags: reflection, go

I read the [reflect document](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Slice) and I'm a little confused about why it doesn't have a `func (v Value) Slice() slice` function, which to get the underlying value from a reflect.Value which holds a slice in.

Is there a convenient way to get the underlying slice from a reflect.Value ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no `Slice() []T` method on `reflect.Value` because there is no return value that would be valid for all slice types. For example, `Slice() []int` would only work for int slices, `Slice() []string` for string slices, etc. `Slice() []interface{}` would also not work, [due to how the slice is stored in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990338/cannot-convert-string-to-interface).

Instead, you can get the underlying slice value by using the [`reflect.Value.Interface()`](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Interface) method along with a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

Example usage:

```
slice, ok := value.Interface().([]SliceElemType)
if !ok {
    panic("value not a []MySliceType")
}
```

Comment: @mh-cbon: OP was looking for a Slice method that returns a slice of the underlying type, sort of like `Bytes() []bytes`. The `Slice` method on `reflect.Value` returns `Value`, something that isn't of the original type. I've clarified that in my answer.

Comment: I think this answer is misleading and that it should clarify that reflect provides the capabilities do deal with the slice, but that for reasons related to the type system there is no shortcut function such `Slice() []<my type>` but a fully functional api. imho.